# When I am trying to install Apache Apollo on ubuntu, it is giving command not found error

Tags: apache2

When I am trying to install Apache Apollo on Ubuntu, it is not getting installed. It is showing 
        apollo: command not found
Permissions to the apollo file are 777. JAVA_HOME is also properly set. Can anybody help me out? I have followed [Official installation guide](http://activemq.apache.org/apollo/documentation/getting-started.html) properly. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Do you need to add /var/lib/mybroker/bin/ to the PATH?

Comment: @Christopher : Thanks for the comment. According to my knowledge, firstly I need to create the broker 'mybroker' using command 'apollo create broker mybroker'. This command will create mybroker folder i.e. /var/lib/mybroker folder. When I run this command, I get error 'apollo : command not found'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the APOLLA documentation (linked in above question) blindly. i.e. I was trying to create broker using

```
cd /var/lib
${APOLLO_HOME}/bin/apollo create mybroker
```

but 'apollo' is sh file. Hence it should be run using 'sh'. When I tried 'sh apollo create mybroker', it worked.